# A question about lists in Python

Tags: python, list

I'm having some trouble with a couple of hmwk questions and i can't find th answer-
How would you write an expression that removes the first or last element of a list?
i.e. One of my questions reads "Given a list named  'alist' , write an expression that removes the last element of  'alist'"

Comment: Please add "Homework" tag to this question

Comment: This might help: http://diveintopython.org/native_data_types/lists.html

Comment: or http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at this? http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html
Particularly at `pop([i])`? 
Your assignment sounds like a standard question in functional programming. Are you supposed to use lambdas?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure its as simple as "alist.pop()"

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you do it in Python -

```
x = range(10) #creaete list
no_first = x[1:]
no_last  = x[:-1]
no_first_last = x[1:-1]
```

**UPDATE:** `del` in list? Never heard of that. Do you mean `pop`?

Comment: "del in list": look into it:  L = range(5); del L[2]; assert L == [0, 1, 3, 4]

Comment: -1 Your answer doesn't remove the element(s) from x -- x is untouched, and it's not an expression, it's an assignment statement. BTW, what does "del in list?" mean??

Comment: @John he never mentioned that I need to work with one `list` only! Also if you are that bent on saving space, then reassign to new list after modification. `x = x[1:-1]`

Comment: @Ned gotit. Not used to this syntax.

Comment: requirement is "write an expression that removes the last element of 'alist'". Yours doesn't. It copies parts of the original list and then rebinds the name to the copy. "after modification"?? Of what?? No modification has taken place, that's the whole point.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a=[1,2,3,4]
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> del a[0]  # delete the first element
>>> a
[2, 3, 4]
>>> del a[-1] # delete the last element
>>> a
[2, 3]
```

It's also possible to delete them both at once

```
>>> 
>>> a=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> del a[::len(a)-1]
>>> a
[2, 3, 4, 5]
```